# Search Facebook Friends by name using Graph API

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I know how to search name in our MySQL Database using `%search%`. But using Graph API, how can we search user's facebook friends by name? I am using taggable_friends to get list of all user's friends. Is there a way to call Facebook Graph's API using `%search%` and get the result JSON with matching friend's names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Search API to search for users by name: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

Comment: That returns list of all users with the similar name but not the ones from access token user's friend list. How do I do that?

Comment: there is no other way. you would have to get taggable_friends and do the search on your own. keep in mind that you are only allowed to use taggable_friends for tagging friends.